# Output of $e^{jw_0n}$ using transfer function $H(e^{jw})$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, signal-processing

[image]

As you can see in the picture, they simply multiplied the input in the $n$ domain with the Transfer function in the $w$ domain, to get the output in the $n$ domain. That's what they did, right?

This doesn't make sense to me. The proper way of doing this is to compute discrete time fourier transform of the input, multiply it with the transform of the transfer function and then do inverse transform.

The reason given is that 'complex exponential are eigensignals'. I have a rough idea about eigenvectors (that they only get scaled on transformations). So I guess something like that is happening here. But the problem is that integral transforms involve change of variable instead of just scaling.

Comment: I am curious about your background, have you taken linear algebra before? If not then this may be a little hard to explain, so it would be nice to know how much you know already.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I have not taken a course. But I can understand that matrices represent linear transformations. I have gone through the 3Blue1Brown series: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0-GT3co4r2y2YErbmuJw2L5tW4Ew2O5B

Comment: Without matrices do you understand what a change of basis means? That's a more conceptual side of linear algebra that is required to understand this. An explanation in words would do just fine. Also I apologize in advance if this feels like a test, this is not my intention at all!

Comment: @NinadMunshi I know that, on doing a Fourier transform, we get coefficients in the $e^{jwn}$ domain or something like that, so that when we sum back that linear combination, we get back our original function. I have a rough idea of change in basis of functions.

Comment: Ok, I can work with that. I'll have an answer up for you soon.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I also just checked the DTFT of $e^{jw_0n}$. It gives back something involving the delta function instead. I've trouble understanding why it's an eigensignal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from the definition of a transfer function. An LTI system $H$ is usually characterized by its impulse response, $h[n]$, but the question is, why?

As you know the impulse response is simply $H(\delta[n])$. In discrete time, we use the Kronecker deltas as our basis. For an LTI system, we can use the resolution of identity to find

$$H(x[n]) = H\left(\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}x[k]\delta[n-k]\right) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} x[k]H(\delta[n-k]) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} x[k]h[n-k] \equiv (x\star h)[n]$$

But let's consider another basis, namely the complex exponential basis, $\{e^{j\omega n}\}$. These guys are the Fourier transform of the Kronecker delta basis, $\{\delta[n-k]\}$. Applying the system to each of these basis vectors individually:

$$H\left(e^{j\omega n}\right) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{j\omega k}h[n-k] = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{j\omega (n-k)}h[k] = e^{j\omega n}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{j\omega -k}h[k] \equiv H\left(e^{j\omega}\right)e^{j\omega n}$$

by recognizing that last equality as the definition of the Fourier transform. Now, for a fixed $\omega$, the transfer function $H\left(e^{j\omega}\right)$ is a constant. In other words the complex exponentials are eigenvectors of the LTI signal with eigenvalue $H\left(e^{j\omega}\right)$, so they have merit as an alternative basis.

Suppose we represented our signals in this basis:

$$x[n] = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}x_ke^{jk\omega_0n}$$

Then the system applied to the signal would be

$$H(x[n]) = H\left(\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}x_ke^{jk\omega_0 n}\right) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} x_kH(e^{jk\omega_0 n}) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} x_kH(e^{jk\omega_0 })e^{jk\omega_0 n}$$

So if you can write your input signal in this basis very nicely, then it becomes easier to compute the output, rather than trying to find the impulse response and computing the convolution by hand.

Comment: As confusing as it is, there are two distinct $H$'s floating around in here. The first is the system, which is a function that eats input signals and spits out output signals. The second $H$ is the transfer function. In signal processing literature it is usually clear from context which is meant, and here it should be clear, too, the only ambiguity being the very last equality of the last line.

Comment: @NinadMunish Still trying to digest the details lol. But I think I got the conclusion. When you apply a linear combination of complex exponential signals, with constant $w_0$, as the input, the LTI system just scales your signal by a constant factor equal to the Fourier transform of the transfer function evaluated at $w_0$. Hence, Complex exponential signals are eigensignals for the transform that the LTI signal performs. I kept thinking they were Eigensignals for DTFT.

Comment: @RyderRude Just to clear up some terminology: the transfer function $\mathbf{is}$ the Fourier transform of the impulse response, we're not taking its Fourier transform. So, yes, complex exponentials are the eigenfunctions for the system (the proper term, signals cannot be "LTI").

Comment: $H(\delta[n-k])$ is the same function for each $k$ but just shifted, right? (Using the time-invariance property). Also, is the impulse response non-zero only at the time the dirac delta input is non-zero, or can it be spread over time even for a momentary input (like dirac delta function)?

Comment: @RyderRude, no the impulse response can be smeared out, it need not only exist at $n=k$

Comment: "But let's consider another basis, namely the complex exponential basis, $\{e^{j\omega n}\}$. These guys are the Fourier transform of the Kronecker delta basis, $\{\delta[n-k]\}$" What do we mean by Fourier transform of a basis? Is this something like converting from one basis vector set to another? What's the matrix transformation analogy for this?